# Windows welcome screen delay

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wifi, login

I'm having an issue with 50+ laptop/desktop machines. When the user logs into the machine with a wired/wireless connection it usually takes up to 5 minutes to get past the "Welcome screen" on Windows 7. However, I have noticed that when the user logs in whilst completely disconnected from the network it loads instantly. This issue also occurs when unlocking the machine (Windows key + L). I am beginning to think this could be a network issue? I have updated the driver on the machines however this doesn't seem to change anything. I'm guessing it could be a network related issue or a domain controller related issue. Also it also seems to be Lenovo L440 machines that are having this issue, but it could be unrelated. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've cross-posted this to StackOverflow (where it is definitely off-topic) and now here. I suggest you delete both questions and post on ServerFault instead.

Comment: To start with enable verbose startup messages on at least one system to see at what stage of the login process things are hanging.

Comment: this can happen if you connect network drives at logon. But to see more details, I need a boot trace, captured by xbootmgr: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like some name resolution issue which results in timeout. You should run packet sniffer between Domain Controller and end station and see what's missing/broken.

Comment: Did a huge sniff and couldn't find anything unusual or broken in the results.

Comment: Upload the dump somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a wait for network issue.

Take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2421599

Comment: Tried this method, didn't resolve anything.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Credant Protector Client was interfering with the login. I uninstalled and works fine!